# Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 10809

Tags: android, cordova

I downloaded PayPal Cordova Plugin for my android app and after editing information (eg. ClientID) and running, this error shows up. I'm really not sure what's wrong and what to do.

```
Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 10809
```

I have already tried: but the number 10809 simply changes. The error is still there.

```
final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

SystemmWebView.java codes:

```
package org.apache.cordova.engine;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewEngine;

/**
 * Custom WebView subclass that enables us to capture events needed for Cordova.
 */


public class SystemWebView extends WebView implements CordovaWebViewEngine.EngineView {
private SystemWebViewClient viewClient;
SystemWebChromeClient chromeClient;
private SystemWebViewEngine parentEngine;
private CordovaInterface cordova;

public SystemWebView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SystemWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

// Package visibility to enforce that only SystemWebViewEngine should call this method.
void init(SystemWebViewEngine parentEngine, CordovaInterface cordova) {
    this.cordova = cordova;
    this.parentEngine = parentEngine;
    if (this.viewClient == null) {
        setWebViewClient(new SystemWebViewClient(parentEngine));
    }

    if (this.chromeClient == null) {
        setWebChromeClient(new SystemWebChromeClient(parentEngine));
    }
}

@Override
public CordovaWebView getCordovaWebView() {
    return parentEngine != null ? parentEngine.getCordovaWebView() : null;
}

@Override
public void setWebViewClient(WebViewClient client) {
    viewClient = (SystemWebViewClient)client;
    super.setWebViewClient(client);
}

@Override
public void setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient client) {
    chromeClient = (SystemWebChromeClient)client;
    super.setWebChromeClient(client);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Boolean ret = parentEngine.client.onDispatchKeyEvent(event);
    if (ret != null) {
        return ret.booleanValue();
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
}
```

SystemWebViewEngine.java:

```
package org.apache.cordova.engine;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewEngine;
import org.apache.cordova.ICordovaCookieManager;
import org.apache.cordova.NativeToJsMessageQueue;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginManager;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;



public class SystemWebViewEngine implements CordovaWebViewEngine {
public static final String TAG = "SystemWebViewEngine";

protected final SystemWebView webView;
protected final SystemCookieManager cookieManager;
protected CordovaPreferences preferences;
protected CordovaBridge bridge;
protected CordovaWebViewEngine.Client client;
protected CordovaWebView parentWebView;
protected CordovaInterface cordova;
protected PluginManager pluginManager;
protected CordovaResourceApi resourceApi;
protected NativeToJsMessageQueue nativeToJsMessageQueue;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

/** Used when created via reflection. */
public SystemWebViewEngine(Context context, CordovaPreferences preferences) {
    this(new SystemWebView(context), preferences);
}

public SystemWebViewEngine(SystemWebView webView) {
    this(webView, null);
}

public SystemWebViewEngine(SystemWebView webView, CordovaPreferences preferences) {
    this.preferences = preferences;
    this.webView = webView;
    cookieManager = new SystemCookieManager(webView);
}

@Override
public void init(CordovaWebView parentWebView, CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebViewEngine.Client client,
          CordovaResourceApi resourceApi, PluginManager pluginManager,
          NativeToJsMessageQueue nativeToJsMessageQueue) {
    if (this.cordova != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    // Needed when prefs are not passed by the constructor
    if (preferences == null) {
        preferences = parentWebView.getPreferences();
    }
    this.parentWebView = parentWebView;
    this.cordova = cordova;
    this.client = client;
    this.resourceApi = resourceApi;
    this.pluginManager = pluginManager;
    this.nativeToJsMessageQueue = nativeToJsMessageQueue;
    webView.init(this, cordova);

    initWebViewSettings();

    nativeToJsMessageQueue.addBridgeMode(new NativeToJsMessageQueue.OnlineEventsBridgeMode(new NativeToJsMessageQueue.OnlineEventsBridgeMode.OnlineEventsBridgeModeDelegate() {
        @Override
        public void setNetworkAvailable(boolean value) {
            webView.setNetworkAvailable(value);
        }
        @Override
        public void runOnUiThread(Runnable r) {
            SystemWebViewEngine.this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(r);
        }
    }));
    bridge = new CordovaBridge(pluginManager, nativeToJsMessageQueue);
    exposeJsInterface(webView, bridge);
}

@Override
public CordovaWebView getCordovaWebView() {
    return parentWebView;
}

@Override
public ICordovaCookieManager getCookieManager() {
    return cookieManager;
}

@Override
public View getView() {
    return webView;
}

@SuppressLint({"NewApi", "SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void initWebViewSettings() {
    webView.setInitialScale(0);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    // Enable JavaScript
    final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);

    // Set the nav dump for HTC 2.x devices (disabling for ICS, deprecated entirely for Jellybean 4.2)
    try {
        Method gingerbread_getMethod =  WebSettings.class.getMethod("setNavDump", new Class[] { boolean.class });

        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        Log.d(TAG, "CordovaWebView is running on device made by: " + manufacturer);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB &&
                android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("HTC"))
        {
            gingerbread_getMethod.invoke(settings, true);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "We are on a modern version of Android, we will deprecate HTC 2.3 devices in 2.8");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Doing the NavDump failed with bad arguments");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "This should never happen: IllegalAccessException means this isn't Android anymore");
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "This should never happen: InvocationTargetException means this isn't Android anymore.");
    }

    //We don't save any form data in the application
    settings.setSaveFormData(false);
    settings.setSavePassword(false);

    // Jellybean rightfully tried to lock this down. Too bad they didn't give us a whitelist
    // while we do this
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
    // Enable database
    // We keep this disabled because we use or shim to get around DOM_EXCEPTION_ERROR_16
    String databasePath = webView.getContext().getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);


    //Determine whether we're in debug or release mode, and turn on Debugging!
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = webView.getContext().getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
    if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0 &&
        android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        enableRemoteDebugging();
    }

    settings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(databasePath);

    // Enable DOM storage
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    // Enable built-in geolocation
    settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);

    // Enable AppCache
    // Fix for CB-2282
    settings.setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1048576);
    settings.setAppCachePath(databasePath);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    // Fix for CB-1405
    // Google issue 4641
    String defaultUserAgent = settings.getUserAgentString();

    // Fix for CB-3360
    String overrideUserAgent = preferences.getString("OverrideUserAgent", null);
    if (overrideUserAgent != null) {
        settings.setUserAgentString(overrideUserAgent);
    } else {
        String appendUserAgent = preferences.getString("AppendUserAgent", null);
        if (appendUserAgent != null) {
            settings.setUserAgentString(defaultUserAgent + " " + appendUserAgent);
        }
    }
    // End CB-3360

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);
    if (this.receiver == null) {
        this.receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                settings.getUserAgentString();
            }
        };
        webView.getContext().registerReceiver(this.receiver, intentFilter);
    }
    // end CB-1405
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void enableRemoteDebugging() {
    try {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "You have one job! To turn on Remote Web Debugging! YOU HAVE FAILED! ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void exposeJsInterface(WebView webView, CordovaBridge bridge) {
    if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android version is old.");
        // Bug being that Java Strings do not get converted to JS strings automatically.
        // This isn't hard to work-around on the JS side, but it's easier to just
        // use the prompt bridge instead.
        return;            
    }
    SystemExposedJsApi exposedJsApi = new SystemExposedJsApi(bridge);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(exposedJsApi, "_cordovaNative");
}


/**
 * Load the url into the webview.
 */
@Override
public void loadUrl(final String url, boolean clearNavigationStack) {
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

@Override
public String getUrl() {
    return webView.getUrl();
}

@Override
public void stopLoading() {
    webView.stopLoading();
}

@Override
public void clearCache() {
    webView.clearCache(true);
}

@Override
public void clearHistory() {
    webView.clearHistory();
}

@Override
public boolean canGoBack() {
    return webView.canGoBack();
}

/**
 * Go to previous page in history.  (We manage our own history)
 *
 * @return true if we went back, false if we are already at top
 */
@Override
public boolean goBack() {
    // Check webview first to see if there is a history
    // This is needed to support curPage#diffLink, since they are added to parentEngine's history, but not our history url array (JQMobile behavior)
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void setPaused(boolean value) {
    if (value) {
        webView.pauseTimers();
    } else {
        webView.resumeTimers();
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    webView.chromeClient.destroyLastDialog();
    webView.destroy();
    // unregister the receiver
    if (receiver != null) {
        try {
            webView.getContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error unregistering configuration receiver: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v1AZOcwvXQ6I6U1uhbPjsVmPsFYUDx2g5hk9uGtXkv4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but it might be that the webview is not fully visible (might be that something is over it or that it is too small). Can you post a little more code? And xml?

Comment: @LomaRoma updated with files I thought was necessary + xml in a google docs. I couldn't seem to put it up here. Appreciate your help and do let me know if you need any more codes!